# Calling a form based on a string within a view

Tags: django, django-views

I'm building out a view within django that will be used to drive the display of several different forms. Each form name is stored within a model instance and is called within the view. Despite the fact that I have this form name, I'm not sure how I can call the form using a string that is equal to the form's name. For example, normally, within a view, you might see something like this for a form called myOwnForm.

```
form = myOwnForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=instance)
```

In my case, the string of 'myOwnForm' is stored in the field formname of myFormModel. As a result, I've tried this.

```
formname = myFormModel.formname
form = formname(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=instance)
```

This fails to call the myOwnForm form. Would you happen to know how I might be able to call the form name using a string that is stored in a variable?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you really need store only name as string? You have to store a form class (`form = MyForm`, and then `form(...)`). If you really want use string, then also create dict(formname=MyForm) for all forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) function of python.
 `eval(expression, globals=None, locals=None)`
The expression argument is parsed and evaluated as a Python expression using the globals and locals dictionaries as global and local namespace

instead of:

```
formname = myFormModel.formname
form = formname(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=instance)
```

it will be

```
formname = eval(myFormModel.formname)
formname.data = request.POST
formname.files = request.FILES
formname.instance = instance
```

Or you can do it with a long string.

```
formname = eval("%s(request.POST,request.FILES,instance=instance)" % myFormModel.formname)'
```

Evrything inside eval() will be considered as python expression

Comment: Wow, this is an amazing answer. How would I handle the request.FILES in this format?

Comment: Note this, i forgot to add the files `formname.files = request.FILES`

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna try it. Create mapping table and use variable with name.

```
formname = 'user
FORM_MODEL = {'user': UserModelForm}
model_form = FORM_MODEL[formname]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Lemayzeur got me up and running though.

Answer (score 0):

If you have all the potential forms contained in the same file (e.g. forms.py), it's as simple as:

```
from MyApp import forms
form_as_str = 'MyForm' # or whatever you're calling it
my_form = getattr(forms, form_as_str)
my_form(request.POST, request.files, instance=instance)
```

Much safer than using eval, which I wouldn't really recommend.